# Multiple dialog opening in JSF having speed issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have requirement like need to open multiple of different dialog over on success page. On success page menu have created which have around 300 menu items, each menu item refers separate xhtml source file. Which I mention in success page like this.

```
<p:dialog header="Terminal Master" id="TRM_MENU" onHide="false" dynamic="true"  maximizable="true" dir="ltr" closeOnEscape="true" minimizable="true" widgetVar="TRM" modal="false" width="600"  fitViewport="true" position="200,50">  
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="{terminalBean.close()}" />
    <ui:include src="TRM.xhtml"/>       
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog header="SERVICE Master" id="SRM_MENU" onHide="false" dynamic="true"  maximizable="true" dir="ltr" closeOnEscape="true" minimizable="true" widgetVar="SRM" modal="false" width="600"  fitViewport="true" position="200,50">  
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="{serviceBean.close()}" />
    <ui:include src="SRM.xhtml"/>       
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog header="Tax Master" id="TXM_MENU" onHide="false" dynamic="true"  maximizable="true" dir="ltr" closeOnEscape="true" minimizable="true" widgetVar="TXM" modal="false" width="600"  fitViewport="true" position="200,50">  
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="{taxBean.close()}" />
    <ui:include src="TXM.xhtml"/> 
</p:dialog>
```

Due to this multiple dialog, which have include scr while updating success page, it seems all xhtml load. It cause lack of speed efficiency. Please any one guide me to overcome from this issue or give some alternative to full requirement.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: use 1 dialog with dynamic content, dynamic header etc?

Answer (score 0):

Once I make the dialog, only one dialog will open at a time. So, I made the changes as:

```
<p:dialog header="Terminal Master" id="TRM_MENU" onHide="false" dynamic="true"  maximizable="true" dir="ltr" closeOnEscape="true" minimizable="true" widgetVar="TRM" modal="false" width="600"  fitViewport="true" position="200,50">  
    <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{terminalBean.close()}" />
    <c:if test="#{login.getmOpendManu().containsKey('TRM')}"> 
        <ui:include src="TRM.xhtml"/>  
    </c:if>
</p:dialog>
```

Now it works fine for my requirement.